# What are the new item types introduced since 3.0.0?

Tags: path-of-exile

When 3.0.0 was being released, I found myself with much less time on my hands, so I had to stop following and playing PoE.

I recently started playing again, but I see that all the new mechanics that found their way into Standard are completely new to me and, for example, I was missing the possibility to open new passages in the pyramid because my item filter is not properly updated.

What are all the new item types that have been added to the base game since the release of 3.0.0? I tried looking into the Wikia, but either I forgot how to look for these things, or I can't find a comprehensive list.

Comment: Is [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/605432-path-of-exile/75632875) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Joachim if I understand correctly those are only items from 3.0.0, so 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 and 3.4 are missing

Comment: Right, sorry, that's literally what you asked for.

Comment: Are you looking for an updated loot filter or do you just want a list of all the new content since 3.0 to build your own?

Comment: @FoxMcCloud I build my own filter, so I am looking for a list of the new item types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is item filter information straight from GGG's official announcements. They also include information such as new item filter enhancements and functionalities, most notably in the 3.4 Delve league announcement. As far as map information I would only look at the newest patch. I will list some notable (or valuable) new items per patch, the div cards listed are worth upwards of 20 Chaos with some worth multiple exalts. Prices checked on poe.ninja and can fluctuate.

[3.1 Abyss league](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2036673)

Notable additions: Stygian Vise belt, considered best in slot for most builds due to the abyssal socket (which holds the equally important abyss jewels) implicit being straight up better than any other implicit. New currency item Orb of Annulment, a little above the value of a divine (currently)

[3.2 Bestiary](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2093501)

Bestiary orbs and nets can be ignored as this content wasn't added to the base game.

Notable: Div cards the Iron bard and World Eater

[3.3 Incursion](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2150238)

Filter additions: HasExplicitMod, StackSize, GemLevel

Notable: Incursion items Stone of Passage and Flashpowder kegs. Multiple Vials used for upgrading Incursion league uniques. Div cards Immortal Resolve, The Celestial Stone, The Samurai's Eye, and The Mayor

[3.4 Delve](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2201188)

Filter Additions: Custom sounds, light beam effects, minimap icons

Notable: Delve items including fossils and resonators. Div card Beauty Through Death

[3.5 Betrayal](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2255461)

Notable: Scarab map fragments, Div cards A Dab of Ink and The Nurse.

Comment: You forgot to note Abyss jewels in 3.1, as they would be equally important as the abyssal sockets.