# Where to look for fractured walls?

Tags: path-of-exile

As mentioned in my previous [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/343552/100233), I have not played quite some leagues.

Noiw, I am trying to explore some of the content that has been added to the main game, but the Delve content is not exactly clear to me.

In a situation like the following:

[image: screenshot]

Where should I look for a fractured wall? I have tried to look all around the hidden location, but the minimap marker never came up.

I am exploring dark passages using flares and try to approach the hidden location from various directions.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to determine where the fractured wall will/should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nodes can either have one, three or four routes away from it, never only two. This means the Harbinger node would connect to the node above and to the left of it, since it only has two connecting routes at the moment.

Go to that node and travel the route leading downwards until you come to the wall. Once it blows up you can go back to the cart and the route will be open to travel to it.